# Enabling Sitecore Device Detection

Tags: device-detection

When trying to run the following code on my local machine

```cs
var _deviceCache = new DeviceDetectionCache();
var device = _deviceCache.GetDeviceInformation(Request.UserAgent)
```

I am getting the following exception

```
device detection is disabled at Sitecore.CES.DeviceDetection
```

Most of the articles I found spoke about how Sitecore uses Netbiscuits to detect devices, and how to set goals based on device detection but I still haven't found anything on where to enable to it, and if I can enable it on a local machine.

Thanks.

Further info : I'm using Sitecore 8.1 (rev. 151207)

Comment: Did you check **Sitecore.CES.DeviceDetection.config** file?
This article might be helpful: https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/device_detection/configure_sitecore_device_detection

Answer (score 2):

In the sitecore/Settings folder, set DeviceDetection.Enabled to true  
Add the enable Sitecore.CES.DeviceDetection.config file in the (App_Config/Include/CES/) folder

Comment: It's already set to true, could there be something else?

Comment: You need to have the Device Detection enabled as part of your license. You can get it from the App Center I believe.